# C# volatile and Nullable

Tags: c#

According to the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx:

The volatile keyword can be applied to reference types.

So why is it illegal to use on a `Nullable<T>`.. a reference type!

Please note that I do not actually need volatile semantics on a `Nullable<T>` field, I encountered this error accidentally and am simply curious.

Comment: as an aside: Don't use volatile. It's broken...

Comment: @MitchWheat: got any reference on that?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Or at least very badly misunderstood by almost everyone (including me).

Comment: Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) isn't a reference type. It's a value type:

```
public struct Nullable<T>
where T : struct, new()
```

Note the `struct` part.

Just because it has a `null` value doesn't make it a reference type... it's a nullable *value* type. See section 4.1.10 of the C# 4 language spec for more details.

Comment: Of course it's physically impossible to represent a value type with null, so while I will accept that the language defines it as 'struct' (and therefore cannot be volatile), I will not accept that it's actually a value type =)

Comment: @Tergiver: You've misunderstood `null`. `Nullable<T>` very definitely *is* a value type, but `null` doesn't mean what you think it means. The `null` literal is convertible to "the null value for any nullable type" - a null *reference* for reference types, or a value where the `HasValue` property is false for a nullable value type.

Comment: No I understand perfectly. Your speaking in the strict sense of the (high-level) language. I tend to think at a lower level. I'm not arguing that you're wrong. You are very much correct.

Comment: @Tergiver: No, I'm speaking at *every* level. `Nullable<T>` *is* a value type, plain and simple. It's as much a value type as `Guid`. If you think of it as a reference type, you *are* misunderstanding it.

Comment: Imagine you are a 32-bit microprocessor and you have a 32-bit integer with a range of [0..2^32-1]. How are you going to represent one more possible value (null)? You cannot. Nullable is strictly a language feature. How it gets implemented is where I was thinking of it as a reference type. You're right, that's a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tergiver: You store it as a 32-bit value *and* a single bit... which are stored together as a value in the same way that multiple fields are encapsulated in other value types. The value of a nullable value type variable is *not* a reference, it's all of the information about a that value. When you use the assignment operator, that creates a copy of both the value and the "is this a real value" Boolean. It's *not* just a language feature - it requires support in the language, the framework *and* the CLR. It's very much a value type *even in implementation*.

Comment: Then I am indeed wrong at every level! Thanks Jon. I'm happy to learn from my mistake.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think by "a single bit" you mean "a single byte + 3 alignment bytes"? :P

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, it's logically storing a single bit - which is then "stored together as a value in the same way that multiple fields are encapsulated in other value types" :)

Comment: I don't know where I got the idea that `Nullable<T>`'s were always boxed, but knowing they are "extended structures" is valuable performance information (where applicable of course).

Answer (score 4):

Nullable is a value type, not a reference type.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx for definition.